# MVC4 code first force database column name

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, ef-code-first

I have the following problem: I have a hierarchy of entities that uses inheritance. I have a two identical fields( the name and type is the same ) in two of the sub-entities. When I try to "Update-Database -Force" on the project EF5 complains that there are there is already a column with name X.

The way EF5 generates the tables is that it actually generates single table and puts there all the fields of the base entity plus the all the fields of the derived entities.

Is there a way to force a different database column name from the property name.
Are there any other solutions( I know it might be architectural problem to duplicate data but making this common will introduce more complex database hierarchy that I don't want to use ).

Thanks:)

Comment: Is this still a problem for you? Do you need more information than the answers provide?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done in one of two ways, either using *Fluent API* or *property attributes* on your class properties.

```
[Column("ColumnName")]
public string PropertyName
{
   get;
   set;
}
```

See [MSDN - ColumnAttribute Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.mapping.columnattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for more details on the column attribute.

Otherwise, use Fluent API. Within your context class-

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
   base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

   modelBuilder.Entity<YourClass>().Property(yc => yc.PropertyName).HasColumnName("ColumnName");
```

See [MSDN - HasColumnName extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.modelconfiguration.configuration.primitivepropertyconfiguration.hascolumnname%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) for more on this method.

The [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/368164/EF-Data-Annotations-and-Code-Fluent) linked by Baximilian will be useful in learning more about this.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you need to change column name in DB for field, so you can use ColumnAttribute.

You can find more information [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/368164/EF-Data-Annotations-and-Code-Fluent)